# Controller not found

Tags: flutter, dart, bottomnavigationview

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:pet_care/Screens/BottomNavBar/nav_controller.dart';
import 'package:pet_care/Screens/Coupons/coupons_view.dart';
import 'package:pet_care/Screens/HomeScreen/home_screen_view.dart';

class BottomNavBarView extends GetView<BottomNavBarController> {
  const BottomNavBarView({Key? key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<BottomNavBarController>(builder: (controller) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: IndexedStack(
            index: controller.selectedIndex,
            children: [
              HomeScreenView(),
              CouponsView(),

            ],
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: controller.selectedIndex,
            onTap: (index) {
              controller.updateselectedindex(index);
            },
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.help),
                label: 'Help',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.local_offer),
                label: 'Coupons',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

In this Code I Found the error :

Here I make the Bottom Navigation Bar with 2 screens:

1. HomeScreenView
2. Couponsview

   Note : I make the HomeScreenController.

Error with the Homescreenview but no problem with couponsview, so give me any suggestions or solution for that.

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following message was thrown building HomeScreenView(dirty):
"HomeScreenController" not found. You need to call "Get.put(HomeScreenController())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>HomeScreenController())"

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  HomeScreenView HomeScreenView:file:///D:/pet_care/lib/Screens/BottomNavBar/nav_view.dart:17:15
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      GetInstance.find (package:get/get_instance/src/get_instance.dart:306:7)
#1      GetView.controller (package:get/get_state_manager/src/simple/get_view.dart:38:37)
#2      HomeScreenView.build (package:pet_care/Screens/HomeScreen/home_screen_view.dart:18:9)
```

Comment: Bind HomeScreenController from BottomNavBarView , So that it can find it, So use Bindings

Answer (score 0):

You have two options
The first way is to bind the controller class as follows

```
Get.put(BottomNavBarController());
```

so that you can use it or
create a baseController class which extends Bindings and override dependencies method
then inside that bind your controller as i said so that controller avalebale globally
then in GetMaterialApp widget pas baseController class to initialBinding property .